# Font awesome syntax in rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, font-awesome

I'm trying to update some icons. Usually this works but one is next to a text_field_tag and it's not working. This is what I used:

```
<%= text_field_tag 'query', fa_icon('search'), params[:query], placeholder: t(:search_placeholder), class: 'form-control' %>
```

The `fa_icon('search')` is the part that I added. Can someone tell me what's wrong with my syntax.

Thanks

Comment: Are you using Gem or Font-awesome plugin ?

Comment: can you explain what do you mean by not working ?

Comment: Due to the lack of capitalization or punctuation, I initially read your question title as a news headline: "Font Awesome in Rails App; Spectators Awed, Humbled". Disappointment was my inevitable response du jour.

Comment: see, the second value of the `text_field_tag` should be a value of the input field. The icon method you are using creates a HTML, which should not be the second argument. But yes you can place it before or after the text field and then style it to meet the need.

Comment: @ArupRakshit I get error `wrong number of arguments (4 for 1..3)`

Comment: @ArupRakshit placing it before give this error `syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting ')' ...fer.append=( fa_icon('search'), text_field_tag 'query', para... ... ^`

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax should be :

```
<%= fa_icon 'search', text: "Search" %>
<%= text_field_tag 'query', params[:query], placeholder: t(:search_placeholder), class: 'form-control' %>
```

Then apply CSS to position the search icon.

Comment: not work for me. return error in line `<%= fa_icon 'search', text: "Search" %>`

Comment: @FaiZalDong May be version issue. What is the error you got?

Comment: @FaiZalDong How did you include FontAwesome in your rails app?

Comment: in gemfile I just put `gem 'font-awesome-sass', '~> 4.6.2'` and also in application.css.sass I put this 2 line codes ` @import "font-awesome-sprockets" ` , ` @import "font-awesome" `